# Why does an array get passed by value some times and not others?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone explain to me this strange behavior in JavaScript? I thought I understood how pass-by-reference and pass-by-value worked, but JavaScript seems to alternate in how it handles this. Two simple examples:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
function reassign(array) { 
  array = [1, 1, 1]; 
}
reassign(arr);
console.log(arr) // [1, 2, 3]

var arr2 = [1, 2, 3];
function withSplice(array) { 
  array.splice(1, 1); 
}
withSplice(arr2);
console.log(arr2) // [1, 3]
```

Where is my thought process failing with this? I feel like the 'reassign' function is receiving a copy of the array, so the reassignment does nothing to the original, but then the 'withSplice' method seems to receive the actual array. What gives? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Arrays (Objects) are always passed by reference. That means the array is not copied across function calls.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Important to be careful with terminology here: "Pass-by-reference" is a term of art meaning that a reference to the **variable** is passed into the function, and the function can change the contents of the **variable**. JavaScript doesn't have that, it **only** has pass-by-value. The value in the case of objects (including arrays) is the object reference. That's completely different from "pass-by-reference." (Basically, two very different meanings of the word "reference.")

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I'm aware that it is impossible to actually pass the variable reference in JavaScript like in other languages such as C++. "Pass by pointer" might even be a better terminology here but I didn't want it too complicated. I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does an array get passed by value some times and not others?

It doesn't. A *reference* to the array is passed (by value) into the function in both cases. In your first snippet, you then *replace* the reference in your `array` variable with a reference to a new array; that `array` variable has nothing to do with your `arr` variable, which keeps referring to the old array. In your second snippet, you modify the *state* of the *original* array that both `array` and `arr` are referring to.

*(More about the terms "pass-by-value" and "pass-by-reference", which have a very specific meaning, below.)*

Let's step back for a second, and then we'll look at your snippets.

In JavaScript (as in many languages), variables contain only primitive values, like (say) the number 15. One kind of primitive value is a *reference* to an array or other kind of object, which exists elsewhere in memory from the variable. These references are values we never see directly that tell the JavaScript engine where to find the array/object elsewhere in memory.

So say we have this code:

```
var n = 15;
var a = [1, 2, 3];
```

Here's some ASCII-art for what we get in memory:

```
+−−−−−+
|  n  |
+−−−−−+
| 15  |
+−−−−−+

+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|      a       |     +−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     | 1 |
| (ref #123)   |−−−−>| 2 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     | 3 |
                     +−−−+
```

`n` contains the value 15; `a` contains an *object reference* that points to the array, elsewhere in memory.

When you pass a variable's value into a function (or assign it to another variable, etc.), a *copy* of the primitive value in it is made. The value that's copied in the case of object references is the object reference; both copies of the reference then refer to the same object. So if we do this:

```
var m = n;
var b = a;
```

We get:

```
+−−−−−+
|  n  |
+−−−−−+
| 15  |
+−−−−−+

+−−−−−+
|  m  |
+−−−−−+
| 15  |
+−−−−−+

+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|      a       |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| (ref #123)   |−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |  +−−−+
                  |  | 1 |
                  +−>| 2 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |  | 3 |
|      b       |  |  +−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
| (ref #123)   |−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

In both cases, the value of the variable was copied to a new variable.

So what's happening in your snippets, then?

In the first snippet, you're giving the `array` variable (argument) a *new* value, a reference to a new array, separate from the original array. Since the `array` variable has no connection to the `arr` variable, `arr` still refers to the original array.

In the second snippet, you're changing the **state** of the original array, not the `array` variable's value. Since both `array` and `arr` refer to that same array, you see that modified state regardless of which copy of the reference you use to look at it.

More ASCII-art:

#### Your first snippet

In your first snippet, you start out with this in memory:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|    arr     |     +−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+     | 1 |
| (ref #123) |−−−−>| 2 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+     | 3 |
                   +−−−+
```

Then when you enter your `reassign` function **before** the `array = [1, 1, 1];` line, you have:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|    arr     |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| (ref #123) |−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |  +−−−+
                |  | 1 |
                +−>| 2 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |  | 3 |
|    array   |  |  +−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
| (ref #123) |−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Each variable contains a copy of the reference to the array.

Then **after** the `array = [1, 1, 1];` line in your `reassign` function but before it returns you have:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|    arr     |     +−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+     | 1 |
| (ref #123) |−−−−>| 2 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+     | 3 |
                   +−−−+

+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|    array   |     +−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+     | 1 |
| (ref #456) |−−−−>| 1 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+     | 1 |
                   +−−−+
```

As you can see, now the variables have references to *different* arrays.

Then your function returns and the `array` variable goes away, and eventually the array you created is garbage-collected.

#### Your second snippet

In your second snippet, you start out with the same thing, and when you go into your `withSplice` function **before** the call to `splice`, you have the same thing you did earlier:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|    arr     |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| (ref #123) |−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |  +−−−+
                |  | 1 |
                +−>| 2 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |  | 3 |
|    array   |  |  +−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
| (ref #123) |−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then you execute your `splice`, changing the state of the array, and you have this:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|    arr     |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| (ref #123) |−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                |  +−−−+
                +−>| 1 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |  | 3 |
|    array   |  |  +−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
| (ref #123) |−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

The **state** of the array both variables point to was changed by `splice`.

---

#### Pass-by-value vs. Pass-by-reference

These terms have a very specific meaning in computer science: They refer to what happens when you pass a variable into a function: Pass-by-value means that the variable's **value** is passed; the function has no knowledge at all of the variable, just the value. Pass-by-reference means a reference **to the variable** is passed; the function could then reach up and modify the variable's value such that the calling code would see the change. So if I had a variable with `15` in it, and passed that *by reference* into a function, the function could change the variable's value to `20` and have that change show up not just within the function, but also in the code that called it when the function returned. It's a completely different usage of the word "reference" from our discussion above, but a rich source of misunderstanding. :-)

JavaScript is purely pass-by-value. Unlike, say, C++ or C#, it doesn't have any pass-by-reference features at all.

Comment: Wow, you wrote this extremely thorough answer minutes after I posted. I completely understand now. Thank you so much!