# confusing execution relating to function, loop and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

Refer to the given below code:
I am not able to understand that what's happening under the hood that let the confusion between the two points mentioned below:

1. when `revArrayInPlace(a)` executes, it change the original value of variable `a` but
2. when `revArray(a)` executes, it doesn't change the original value of variable `a`

In `revArrayInPlace(a)`, `if(x[someIndex] = someValue)` replace the original value of `x[someIndex]`with `somevalue` , then logically `x = newArray` should also replace the original value of array `x`with new value `newArray` when revArray(a) executes

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

function revArray(x) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = x.length -1; i >= 0 ; i = i-1) {
        result.push(x[i]);
    }
    x = result; 
}



function revArrayInPlace(x) {
  for (var i = 0; i<Math.floor(x.length/2); i=i+1) {
    var old = x[i];
    x[i] = x[x.length - 1 - i];
    x[x.length -1 -i] = old;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Your "point 1" is wrong. The function does **not** change the value of `a`. It changes the contents of the array, but `a` remains the same; it continues to refer to the same array object.

Comment: @Pointy yeah I mean that itself

Comment: I've removed the part of my answer you folded into the question. It's important not to fold answers into the question, because people finding this later to try to use it to solve their problem are faced with an apparently non-sensical answer that just repeats part of the question (as far as they can see).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of `revArray`, you're doing this:

```
x = result;
```

That does nothing to modify the original array or the original variable (`a`, I think) referring to it (but it's a common misunderstanding, you're not the only one!). All it does is modify the value in `x`, changing it from being a reference to the original array to being a reference to the new array. Since the next thing you do is exit the function, that doesn't accomplish anything.

In JavaScript, only **values** are passed into functions, not variables. So:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
revArray(a);
```

...reads the *value* from `a` and passes that value into `revArray`. That value tells the JavaScript engine where the array is, but it has no ongoing connection to the `a` variable at all. If you think about it, it has to be that way, because you can pass the result of an expression into a function; then what would assigning to the argument do? :-)

To make `revArray` work, *return* the result:

```
return result;
```

...and call it like this:

```
a = revArray(a);
```

Example:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];

function revArray(x) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = x.length -1; i >= 0 ; i = i-1) {
        result.push(x[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

a = revArray(a);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: I tried executing `revArray(a)` after adding `return result` but still it doesn't change the original value of a

Comment: you quoted "In JavaScript, only values are passed into functions, not variables" and "That value tells the JavaScript engine where the array is, but it has no ongoing connection to the `a` variable at all". Then how come `revArrayInPlace` able to change the original value of `a`inspite of the fact "only values are passed into functions, not variables. it has no ongoing connection to the `a` variable at all"

Comment: @Andrew: `revArrayInPlace` doesn't change the value of `a` at all. Remember, the value of `a` is where, in memory, the array is. `revArrayInPlace` changes the contents of the array, not the value of `a`.

Comment: @Andrew: *"I tried executing revArray(a) after adding return result but still it doesn't change the original value of a"* The `return` is only half of it; look at the answer again: *"...and call it like this: `a = revArray(a);`"*

Comment: yeah i know `a = revArray(a)` will work. Shall i take it as that the content can be changed of the variable but not a value? Actually I am curious to know that how does it happen (content gets changed but not the value). can you refer me some reference where can let me explain what's actually going under the hood.

Comment: @Andrew: Again: Changing the array isn't changing the *variable* at all, because the array isn't in the variable; a *reference* to the array (like a number telling the JavaScript engine where the array is) is in the variable. [This answer of mine from a couple of years back](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28826417/157247) might help.

Comment: I am greatly thankful to you for your this vital information. Every is making sense to me now.